# Oracle : table or view doesn't exist?

Tags: oracle

I have a schema in oracle in which I have some tables, let's say Table1 (I'm sure it exists)

When I query the table using the **same** **schema** :

```
select * from Table1;
```

I have the error **"table or view doesn't exit"**

I suspect something related to table space... because when I created the user

```
CREATE USER MyUser IDENTIFIED BY password DEFAULT TABLESPACE MyTableSpace;
```

I set a different default table space.

I tried

```
select * from MyTableSpace.Table1; 
select * from MyUser.Table1;
```

But that was unsuccesful.

Does anyone have an idea please ?

Thanks.

Comment: First off, the preceding qualifier on a table is the schema name, not a tablespace, so "MyTableSpace.Table1" certainly is not correct.  Did you check if there is some sort of public synonym on the table.  What if you "select * from MyUser.Table1"?

Comment: "select * from MyUser.Table1" returns the same error

Comment: You are logged in as MyUser?

Comment: Yes, I'm logged as MyUser in SQL Developper and I can see the table.

Comment: Have you tried logging in from sqlplus directly?  Can you login as SYS on your database?

Comment: Yes I can. I tried "select * from MyUser.Table1" but still nothing...

Comment: You also need the appropriate grants on the table or view to query it.

Comment: Did you login as MyUser and then create the table? Or you created it as SYS? Did you use mixed case for the table name? If you login as SYS, try `SELECT * FROM DBA_TABLES WHERE UPPER(TABLE_NAME)='TABLE1';`

Comment: If you are using SQL Developer, can you expand the "Tables" tree under the connection? If so, can you see the table there?

Comment: Yes the tables were created after the user, and are created by this user in the same sceham And when I expend the tables tree in SQL Developper, I can see the tables.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly - you have two users (schemes) -User1,User2.
You logged into SQL Developer as User1 and then created Table1.
Then You login into SQL Developer as User2 and try to execute `select * from Table1` and  `select * from User1.Table1` and it is unsuccessful.

So first you have to grant select access on User1.Table1 to User2.
To do this you have to login as User1 and execute

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON Table1 TO User2;
```

After this will be able to execute query (When you are logged in as User2)

```
select * from User1.Table1;
```

then you have to create synonym in order not to use prefix User1. To do this - loggin as User2 and execute

```
CREATE SYNONYM Table1 FOR User1.Table1;
```

Now you can loggin as User2 and execute:

```
select * from User1.Table1;
```

Comment: I have only one user. As specified in the first post : "When I query the table using the SAME schema". I mentionned nowhere User2...